# How do I find the last start time for a Hyper-V virtual machine?

Tags: hyper-v

We're using the Hyper-V role on Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows Server 2012.

We have some virtual machines which are powered off.  How can I find out when they were last run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked it out - the timestamp on the `.vhd` file will change only when the VM is in use, so that's the last time it was run.

Comment: That will give you a good indication of when the VM was shut down. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Knowing when it was last shut down is good enough for my purpose.  Another way of finding both the last start and last shutdown would be to boot the VM and look at it's own event log / syslog (assuming the clock is accurate) but obviously that will take longer per machine and will use resources on the host.